# jQuery form submit - prevent.default - ajax email - the submit form to PayPal

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, preventdefault

I have a php page with the following code. I'm trying to prevent deafault form submission to PayPal until I have updated the hidden #amount field and sent an email via an ajax call.

Current problem is that the email is sent multiple times due to the jquery submit form call in the ajax success method and the form never gets submitted to PayPal.

I had tried changing the #process_form button to type 'button' instead of submit, and changing the $('#checkout-form').submit(function(event) { to $('#process_form').click(function() { -- but my ajax email never got sent.

Help appreciated.

```
    <form id="checkout-form" name="Payment" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$pymtEmail?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="75.00"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="xxxxx"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="0"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="random_invoice" name="custom" value="<?php echo rand ( 1000 , 10000 ) ?>"/>
        <div id="applicants">
            <div class="applicant">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Applicant Information</legend>
                    <div id="name">
                        <label class="n_first">
                            <span>First Name:</span>
                            <input id="applicant_first_name" class="applicant_first_name" name="applicantFirstName" placeholder="" type="text" required>
                        </label>
                        <label class="n_last">
                            <span>Last Name:</span>
                            <input id="applicant_last_name" class="applicant_last_name" name="applicantLastName" placeholder="" type="text" required>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            <span>Email Address:</span>
                            <input id="applicant_email" class="applicant_email" name="applicantEmail" placeholder="A working email address must be used or we will not complete your screening." type="email" required>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button id="removebutton" type="button" class='button removeapplicant'>Remove Applicant</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button id="addbutton" type="button" class='button addapplicant'>Add Applicant</button>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Billing Information</legend>
            <div id="name">
                <label class="n_first">
                    <span>First Name:</span>
                    <input id="first_name" name="billingFirstName" placeholder="" type="text" autocomplete="given-name" required>
                </label>
                <label class="n_last">
                    <span>Last Name:</span>
                    <input id="last_name" name="billingLastName" placeholder="" type="text" autocomplete="family-name" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Email Address:</span>
                    <input id="email" name="billingEmail" placeholder="Please provide a working email address." type="email" autocomplete="email" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Phone Number:</span>
                    <input id="phone_number" name="billingPhone" placeholder="" type="tel" autocomplete="tel" pattern="^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$" required>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input id="terms_and_conditions" name="terms_and_conditions" type="checkbox" required>
                    <span>I agree to the Terms and Conditions (See below: You must agree to continue)</span>
                </label>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
            <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit" id="process_form" data-text="...Submitting">Submit Order</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p><br />Questions about this process? Please Call us at <?=$contact_phone?>.</p>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<script>
    var counter = 1;
    var template = $('#applicants .applicant:first').clone();
    var applicantsCount = 1;
    //add applicant
    $('body').on('click', '.addapplicant', function() {
        applicantsCount++;
        var applicant = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){
            var newId = this.id + applicantsCount;
            $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);
            this.id = newId;
            this.name = newId;
        }).end()
        .appendTo('#applicants');
        counter = counter + 1;
        return false;
    });
    //remove applicant
    $('#applicants').on('click', '.removeapplicant', function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(this).parent().empty();
            return false;
        });
        counter = counter - 1;
        return false;
    });


    // Submit Form
    $('#checkout-form').submit(function(event) {
        // Process form before submission
        event.preventDefault()

        // Update the #amount field for payment (applicants * $75)
        //alert('counter: ' + counter);
        var total = 0;
        total = counter * 75;
        $('#amount').val(total);

        // Send email with pertinent form information
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://example.com/sendapplicantinfo',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data : $('#checkout-form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                //alert('email sent');
                $('#checkout-form').submit();
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that works - improvements?
I switched the #process_form button back to type=button
I added another (hidden) submit button
I changed the //Submit Form code

Code follows:
    Submit Order

```
$('#process_form').click(function(event) {
        // Process form before submission
        //event.preventDefault()

        // Update the #amount field for payment (applicants * $75)
        //alert('counter: ' + counter);
        var total = 0;
        total = counter * 75;
        $('#amount').val(total);

        // Send email to Gail with all form information
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://onsitedrugtesting.net/sendapplicantinfo',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data : $('#checkout-form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                //alert('email sent');
                //$('#checkout-form').submit();
                $('#submit_form').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    });
```